# jQuery How to remove appended audio tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am maintaining someone else's code in my new job, In a big websuite type project there is a part where there is an append to the body that I am re implementing with audio tag instead of embed tag. I am having trouble removing it.

Here is how it used to be:

```
$('body').append('<embed id="infrSound' + this.id + '" src="' + this.soundfile + '" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true" repeat="true" style="display:block; width:0px; height:0px;">');
```

Here is how it used to be removed:

```
$('embed#infrSound' + this.id).remove();
```

Here is how it works now:

```
 $('body').append('<audio controls autoplay="autoplay" loop="true" hidden="true" repeat="true"><source id="infrSound' + this.id + '" src="' + this.soundfile + '"></audio>');
```

How would I go about removing the sound in this new implementation?

Comment: Have you tried to Put an id in the audio tag, and then remove the audio tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('source#infrSound' + this.id).parent().remove();
```

which is to say, use the same ID as before, then go up to its parent, which is the new audio tag, then remove that.

Test and example: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/pcarjob9/

Comment: The 'source' part is redundant, since the selector also contains an id (#...), which is (or should be) unique in the page. Only using id gives better performance (webbrowsers can then use the native document.getElementById() call):
$('#infrSound' + this.id)

Comment: Guno makes a good point, albeit the performance difference is largely insignificant nowadays...? I did it the way I did for clarity, in terms of helping RRajg get to grips with how he could change his code and help him see what is being changed and why.

Comment: This didnt seem to work for some reason, is it true that audio started with audio tag cannot be stopped?

Comment: No, .remove() should do it, I just added a fiddle to check. I wonder where it is going wrong at your end - do you have any more code you can share?

Comment: It wasnt working, somehow the volume went down though!

I simplified the append part to this

    
        $('body').append('<audio autoplay id="infrSound' + this.id + '" src="' + this.soundfile + '" loop="true" hidden="true"></audio>');

Comment: More I test this the more it seems the file is playing twice, and on remove one is stopped hence the change in volume. I am not sure what is going on here!

Comment: you could do $("audio").remove() to simply remove *all* audio elements from the page!

Comment: Finally figured out what was going on, the autoplay was starting two instances of the sound file, so when I removed it, it only removed one of the two hence the lowering of volume! Got rid of the autoplay and did a manual play in the next line! Thanks for the help!